# Django split urls.py into submodule

Tags: python, django

let's say i have long urls.py and would love to split into

```
urls/
    a_urls.py
    b_urls.py
    c_urls.py
```

is this possible?

Note: there is app_name in urls.py.

Comment: not sure, but doesn't it work to create a list or urls in each file, and then in  `urls.py`, import them and append them or join them?

Answer (score 3):

I think the following will work. In theory, when looking for something in the module/package `urls`, it will look into the `__init__.py` file insider this package. I am assuming that inside of those mentioned files you have a list `urlpatterns` in which you have listed your urls.

In **__init__.py**:

```
from .a_urls import urlpatterns as a_urls
from .b_urls import urlpatterns as b_urls
from .c_urls import urlpatterns as c_urls


app_name = 'your_app_name'


urlpatterns = [
    # all your other urls
]

urlpatterns += a_urls
urlpatterns += b_urls
urlpatterns += c_urls
```

I think because of performance you could use `urlpatterns.extend(a_urls)` and so on.

Comment: is it possible to make it submodule like views.py split into views/ with __init__.py ?

Comment: @TianLoon, I got your point. I think will be possible to have a package called `urls`, and to put the logic in the `__init__.py` file.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I've found for now (I still don't think it's ideal) is the following, which I'll demonstrate by example:

I changed

```
app_1/urls.py
```

to

```
app_1/urls/
  __init__.py
  urls.py
  topic_a.py
```

---

My application was like this:

app_1/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from app_1.views import topic_a_views

app_name = 'app_1'
urlpatterns = [
    path(
        'topic_a/first_view/',
        topic_a_views.FirstView.as_view(),
        name='topic_a/first_view',
    ),
    # ... other paths for all topics
]
```

Some template.html

```
<a href="{% url 'app_1:topic_a/first_view' %}">First view</a>
```

Some code.py

```
reverse('app_1:topic_a/first_view')
```

---

Now my application is like this:

app_1/urls/__init__.py

```
from .urls import *
```

app_1/urls/urls.py

```
from django.urls import include, path

app_name = 'app_1'
urlpatterns = [
    path('topic_a/', include('app_1.urls.topic_a')),
    # ... other paths for non topic_a topics
]
```

app_1/urls/topic_a.py

```
from django.urls import path

from app_1.views.topic_a_views import FirstView

urlpatterns = [
    path(
        'first_view/',
        FirstView.as_view(),
        name='topic_a/first_view',
    ),
    # ... other paths for topic_a
]
```

The ".html" and ".py" files remained the same.

Some template.html

```
<a href="{% url 'app_1:topic_a/first_view' %}">First view</a>
```

Some code.py

```
reverse('app_1:topic_a/first_view')
```

---

What I still don't like about this solution:

- I would prefer a viewname like '**app_1:topic_a:first_view**', instead of '**app_1:topic_a/first_view**', just because it makes more sense.
- And most importantly, it would be better to define the path function's name argument with just '**first_view**' instead of '**topic_a/first_view**', because I need to repeat '**topic_a/**' in every name argument.